Is compact-open topology stable with respect to injective limits?
Let $X$ be a locally convex space, and $\{Y_i;\ i\in I\}$ a covariant system of locally convex spaces over a partially ordered set $I$, i.e. a system of linear continuous mappings is given $\sigma^j_i:Y_i\to Y_j$, $i\le j\in I$ such that
$$
\sigma^k_j\circ\sigma^j_i=\sigma^k_i, \qquad i\le j\le k\in I.
$$
(We assume that all locally convex spaces are over a common field, say, $\mathbb C$. If necessary, we can think that $X$ and $Y_i$ are complete.)
Let $Y$ be the injective limit of $\{Y_i;\ i\in I\}$ in the category of locally convex spaces
$$
Y=\injlim_{i\in I}Y_i.
$$
For each $i\in I$ we consider the space ${\mathcal L}(X,Y_i)$ of operators (i.e. linear continuous mappings) $\varphi:X\to Y_i$ endowed with the compact-open topology. Similarly, we endow the space ${\mathcal L}(X,Y)$ of operators $\varphi:X\to Y$ with the compact-open topology.
The family of spaces $\{{\mathcal L}(X,Y_i);\ i\in I\}$ is also a covariant system over $I$, and we can consider its injective limit
in the category of locally convex spaces:
$$
\injlim_{i\in I}{\mathcal L}(X,Y_i).
$$
There is a natural mapping
$$
\omega:\injlim_{i\in I}{\mathcal L}(X,Y_i)\to {\mathcal L}(X,Y).
$$
Question:

Is it true that the topology of $\injlim_{i\in I}{\mathcal L}(X,Y_i)$ is inherited from ${\mathcal L}(X,Y)$?

In other words,

if $U$ is a neighbourhood of zero in $\injlim_{i\in I}{\mathcal L}(X,Y_i)$ do there always exist a compact set $T\subseteq X$ and a neighbourhood of zero $V$ in $Y$ such that
$$
U\supseteq \omega^{-1}(\{\varphi\in{\mathcal L}(X,Y):\ \varphi(T)\subseteq V\} )
$$
?


If I understand your question correctly, the answer is no in this generality (let $X$ be a large vector space regarded as the lcs inductive (=? injective) limit of its finite dimensional subspaces.  Then the identity mapping on $X$ doesn‘t factor through a component).  On the positive side, there was a considerable amount of work done in the golden age of lcs theory on special situations—Involving, e.g., $\cal F$- and $\cal {LF}$-spaces.  For example, by Grothendieck in his thesis.

@crow I don't understand you. Do you mean that the mapping $\injlim_{i\in I}{\mathcal L}(X,Y_i)\to {\mathcal L}(X,Y)$ is not necessarily surjective? I understand this, my question is not about this. I'll edit it.

The answer to your question is certainly negative. Before giving a reference let me spell out what it means that the injection $\injlim L(X,Y_i) \to L(X,\injlim Y_i)$ is an isomorphism onto its range: $0$-neighbourhoods in
$\injlim L(X,Y_i)$ are absolutely convex hulls of unions of the form $W_i=\{T\in L(X,Y_i): T(K_i)\subseteq V_i\}$ where $K_i$ are compact in $X$ and $V_i$ are $0$-neighbourhoods in $Y_i$ whereas a $0$-neighbourhood $W$ in $L(X,Y)$ is defined by a single compact set $K\subseteq X$ and a $0$-neighbourhood $V$ in $\injlim Y_i$. You need that, for all such $W_i$ there is one $W$ with $$W\cap \injlim L(X,Y_i) \subseteq \Gamma(\bigcup_i W_i).$$
Despite the difficulty that you have to decompose continuous linear operators in a uniform way, you first have to manufacture some candidates for $V$ depending on the given $V_i$ -- a natural first try would be the absolutely convex hull of the union of the $V_i$ -- and, in particular, for a compact set $K$ depending on the given $K_i$ -- and without further very special requirements for $X$ and/or $Y$ you have no chance even for countable inductive limits.
As a reference with much more information about such problems I recommend the work

Susanne Dierolf, On spaces of continuous linear mappings between locally convex spaces, Note Mat. 5, 147-255 (1985). http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/notemat/article/view/1621

Concrete counterexamples for $Y$ even a countable locally convex direct sum of the field are contained in chapter 2, $X$ can be taken as a product $\mathbb K^I$ for a set $I$ of cardinality at least that of $\mathbb R$.

Jochen, I need some time to find this paper by Susanne Dierolf.

@SergeiAkbarov I added a link

Thanks for adding the link.
